# Swift IOS 13, IAP - "Cannot connect to Itunes Connect"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am using IOS 13.5 and am running into some problems when implementing IAP. I used this same exact code when i built a previous app and the payment works fine when i test run the previous app on the same physical device as i do now.

I have checked internet connection which is fine, Certificates looks good, the IAP in Itunes Connect is "Ready to submit", IAP is enabled for the app, i have made several sandbox testers with same results. I clean built and restarted computer and device but It always says Code=2 "cannot connect to Itunes Connect"

I even tried to upload a build to Itunes connect to see if it would make a difference, it didn't. I am clearly missing something and would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

**Calling for purchase initiation:**

```
IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .fullAccess)
```

**IAPService:**

```
class IAPService: NSObject {

private override init() {}
static let shared = IAPService()

var products = [SKProduct]()
let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

func getProducts() {
    let products: Set = [IAPProduct.fullAccess.rawValue]
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
    paymentQueue.add(self)
}

func purchase(product: IAPProduct){
    guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue}).first else { return }
    let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
    paymentQueue.add(payment)
}

func restorePurchases(){
    print("restoring purchases")
    GlobalVariables.hasFullAccess = false
    GlobalVariables.partialAccessArrayKeys.removeAll()
    paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    CheckPurchase.shared.checkUserPurchase()
}}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        for product in response.products {
            print(product.localizedTitle)
        }
    }
}

extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.transactionState)
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
            print(transaction.debugDescription)
            if transaction.error != nil {
                print(transaction.error)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .deferred: return "deferred"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        case .purchased: return "purchased"
        case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
        case .restored: return "restored"
        }
    }
}
```

**IAPProduct:**

```
enum IAPProduct : String {
    case fullAccess = "se.marcusthuvesen.Torst.FullAccess"
}
```

App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    IAPService.shared.getProducts()
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    //Load game texts from FireBase
    return true
}}
```

Comment: On AppStoreConnect, under your `iOS App` settings, under `In-App Purchases`. Have you added your "Full Access" in app purchase to the list? have you updated all your apple agreements and contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add yourself as an observer to the paymentQueue in the App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions callback.

Where are you seeing the error message? You should see the SKProductsRequestDelegate callbacks first.

Comment: Do i really need to do that? It worked in my other app without doing so. What do you mean by adding an observer to the paymentqueue?

Comment: It is imperative for StoreKit to work correctly that you are an observer to the payment queue at all times - so for the full lifetime of the app. "Your application should add an observer to the payment queue during application initialization." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506042-add

Comment: I added my App delegate code in the question. I tried to implement the observer but this is the way to do it?

Comment: Add yourself as an SKPaymentQueue observer in the init method of the IAPService class. Then in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, invoke the shared instance to create the object and keep it alive - which you're doing right now, but make sure you always do this, and don't remove the call. Remove the duplicate line from getProducts. This shared instance should now be an observer to any SKPaymentQueue updates - great. This isn't going to fix your problem. Can you tell us when you receive the error message, is it after fetching products or when you attempt to purchase one?

Comment: Ok, I will change this. The error message occurs when i try to purchase the product.

Comment: So do the products get returned to you okay? Have you checked your contracts?